# Importing excel has an error of "Illegal string offset" in my controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import an excel to my database table 'users' but it has an error saying Illegal string offset "email". I tried deleting the "email" then it says that Illegal string offset "username" now. Is it really the error in controller? Or maybe the reason is that i also have a repository. 
This is my code for the controller

```
public function userImport()
{
    if( Input::file('file_import') ) {
        $path = Input::file('file_import')->getRealPath();
        $inserts = [];
        Excel::load($path,function($reader) use (&$inserts)
        {
        foreach ($reader->toArray() as $rows){
            foreach($rows as $row){
                $inserts[] = ['email' => $row['email'], 'username' => $row
                ['username'], 'password' => $row['password'], 'first_name' => $row['first_name'],'middle_name' => $row['middle_name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name'], 'gender' => $row['gender'],
                 'civil_status' => $row['civil_status'], 'spouse' => $row['spouse'], 'religion' => $row['religion'],'emergency_no' => $row['emergency_no'],'previous_work' => $row['previous_work'],
                 'remarks' => $row['remarks'],'course' => $row['course'],'biometrics' => $row['biometrics'],'immediate_head' => $row['immediate_head'],'designation' => $row['designation'],'level' => $row['level'],
                 'emp_status' => $row['emp_status'],'dependents' => $row['dependents'],'date_hired' => $row['date_hired'],'regularization_date' => $row['regularization_date'],'remmitance_date' => $row['remmitance_date'],
                 'tin' => $row['tin'],'philhealth' => $row['philhealth'],'pagibig' => $row['pagibig'],'sss' => $row['sss'],'umid' => $row['umid'],'phone' => $row['phone'],'avatar' => $row['avatar'],
                 'address' => $row['address'],'country_id' => $row['country_id'],'role_id' => $row['role_id'],'birthday' => $row['birthday'],'status' => $row['status']];
            }
        }
        });
    }  

    if (!empty($inserts)) {
        DB::table('users')->insert($inserts);
        return back()->with('success','Inserted Record successfully');                  
    }

    return back();
}
```

Comment: try accessing `$row` using numerical index instead of `string keys`, by simply dumping a `$row` will tell you if you should use numerical index or string index.

Comment: Can you show me an example on like how to do it? @Wreigh

Comment: try `$row[0]` instead of `$row['email']` since it's probably the first element in the array. moreover, you can `dd($rows)` to see if the array's indices are numerical or not.

Comment: I tried doing $row[0], then the error moved on to the next column , the username. so now it says Illegal string offset "username". I also tried doing dd($rows) and it showed me an array @Wreigh

Comment: apply it to all columns.

Comment: After putting $rows[0] to all the columns, should i also add dd($rows) after? @Wreigh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179344/discussion-between-gwapo-and-wreigh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your dumped `$rows`, it looks like that you don't need another `foreach` inside another `foreach`, modify your code.

```
// readability purpose
$rows = $reader->toArray();

foreach ($rows as $row){
    $inserts[] = ['email' => $row['email'], 'username' => $row
    ['username'], 'password' => $row['password'], 'first_name' => $row['first_name'],'middle_name' => $row['middle_name'], 'last_name' => $row['last_name'], 'gender' => $row['gender'],
     'civil_status' => $row['civil_status'], 'spouse' => $row['spouse'], 'religion' => $row['religion'],'emergency_no' => $row['emergency_no'],'previous_work' => $row['previous_work'],
     'remarks' => $row['remarks'],'course' => $row['course'],'biometrics' => $row['biometrics'],'immediate_head' => $row['immediate_head'],'designation' => $row['designation'],'level' => $row['level'],
     'emp_status' => $row['emp_status'],'dependents' => $row['dependents'],'date_hired' => $row['date_hired'],'regularization_date' => $row['regularization_date'],'remmitance_date' => $row['remmitance_date'],
     'tin' => $row['tin'],'philhealth' => $row['philhealth'],'pagibig' => $row['pagibig'],'sss' => $row['sss'],'umid' => $row['umid'],'phone' => $row['phone'],'avatar' => $row['avatar'],
     'address' => $row['address'],'country_id' => $row['country_id'],'role_id' => $row['role_id'],'birthday' => $row['birthday'],'status' => $row['status']];
}
```

`$rows` already represents *each* row, so you should probably rename it to `$row`.

Comment: Oh okay it worked. So which means I only need one foreach for it. Thank you so much!